# Read and insert files from SVN repository from JAVA code

Tags: java

I want to create a UI portal where in I can display the SVN files in UI and access the SVN from JAVA code. Could someone please help with the sample code and how this can be achieved.

Comment: Did you try any thing or u looking for source code from here?

Answer (score 1):

For begining you can start with using an open source library SVN Kit
http://svnkit.com/